# @font-face not working on Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css, font-face

I used @font-face and I uploaded all fonts in .ttf, .eot and .woff format. 
It works well on Firefox but Chrome and Safari all the texts turn to Times New Roman.
Here is the code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Open Sans Regular';
src: url(../open_sans/OpenSans-Regular.eot);
src: url("../open_sans/OpenSans-Regular.woff") format('woff');
src: local('Open Sans'), url('../open_sans/OpenSans-regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have very cool website for this named as : http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator
Also, modified your code as well.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'open_sansregular';
src: url('../open_sans/OpenSans-Regular.eot');
src: url('../open_sans/OpenSans-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../open_sans/OpenSans-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../open_sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../open_sans/OpenSans-Regular.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

PS: Apparently  open sans is google font if so then its easy to use google code for embedding, it is too reliable. URL: [http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans](http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace%3ause/Collection%3aOpen+Sans)
Let me know if still find issues.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for an @font-face include is this (if you have all those files offcourse):

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'FontName';
   src: url('FileName.eot');
   src: url('FileName.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('FileName.woff') format('woff'),
        url('FileName.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('FileName.svg#FontName') format('svg');
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: normal;
}
```

Also make sure your htaccess allows webfonts:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Webfont access
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Allow access from all domains for webfonts.
# Alternatively you could only whitelist your
# subdomains like "subdomain.example.com".

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Webfonts
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject  eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf         ttf ttc
AddType font/opentype                  otf
AddType application/x-font-woff        woff
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

or you can use

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans-Regular';
    src: url('OpenSans-Regular.eot');
    src: local('OpenSans-Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), 
    url('OpenSans-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('OpenSans-Regular.svg#OpenSans-Regular') format('svg'), 
    url('OpenSans-Regular.otf') format('opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```